# Template literals inside of quotation marks

Tags: javascript, syntax, template-literals, quotation-marks

How can I write this so it works?

```
document.getElementById("td-`${i}`")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a template literal **instead** of the quoted string, not inside it:

```js
document.getElementById(`td-${i}`)
// Here ----------------^-------^
```